# How to - View sound percentage?

Tags: sound, gui

Is there a way to make Ubuntu show me the current main volume level in the form of a percent? Like Windows 7 does when you change the sound level.
I'm just sorta a number freak, and I like to know what percentage my volume is at. Thanks :)

Comment: Assuming you refer to the GNOME version, there is a proposal to integrate it into an extension [1](https://github.com/aleho/gnome-shell-volume-mixer/issues/86).

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal you can use `amixer` to ask for the volume. For example my *Master* volume:

```
user@srv % amixer get Master
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono: Playback 21 [68%] [-15.00dB] [on]
```

To get a visual feedback use `notify-send` (from [libnotify-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libnotify-bin&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)):

```
user@srv % notify-send "volume" "$(amixer get Master | grep dB | sed 's/\(^[a-z0-9 :]\+\[\|\[\|\]\)//gi')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your mouse over the volume icon in the panel, the percent should show in a tooltip. I don't think the built-in Gnome applet has a feature like the one you describe.

Comment: It doesn't for me..

Answer (score 0):

Pulse audio control "pavcontrol" from the software centre displays percentage.