# How to show volume level when changing sound volume using custom shortcuts.

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, pulseaudio

On Ubuntu when changing sound volume with keyboard it increasing or decreasing too much for me (something like 5% or 10%).

I wanted to change the volume with 1% every time keyboard button is pressed.

So I assigned custom shortcuts for a command `amixer -D pulse sset Master 1%+`

**But now, when I use those buttons I don't see a box notifying about the current sound level. How do I invoke it?**

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/36718/how-to-view-sound-percentage

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks, the second answer with PPA package and `dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/sound/volume-step 1` works like a charm. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes. Nathan is a bright fellow.